# How to map to references if it's not an Iterator<Item=&T>?

Tags: rust, iterator, borrow-checker

I have a function that receives Iterator<Item=AsRef> and I wanted to get an array of substrings form this iterator. The issue is that when mapping, `.map()` gets ownership of AsRef and I can't return `as_ref()`. How can I turn this iterator into an iterator of references like with Vec::iter? Sample code:

```
fn a(lines: impl Iterator<Item=impl AsRef<str>>) {
    println!("{:?}", lines.map(|s| s.as_ref()).collect::<Vec<&str>>());
}

a(vec!["one".to_string(), "two".to_string()].iter());
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you tried with a `for` loop (you should include it in your question!), but when I translate your functional style code with a `for` loop, it [doesn't work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0a2204b80824e52249452e87b431ad7a) either.

Comment: It's actually not working as you pointed out. I removed that section from the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a bit problematic to do with just an iterator. As signature describes, iterator can very match own the `Item`(s) and transfer the ownership to you inside the closure. Consider taking `&impl AsRef<str>` instead. This should not be a problem to provide at the caller site.

## EDIT

> It is actually tricky on the caller side too. Im using a ReadBuf that returns an Iterator<Item=String>. How would you turn this iterator into an Iterator<Item=&String>?

BufRead will read lines as you demand them and it is designed to wait on the input. To use it properly and with memory efficiency, I'd recommend processing each line in a loop and discarding it before reading the next.

> That's the solution I found but it seems very costly having to allocate an entire Vec just to get the references of items I already own in the iterator.

Iterator does not in fact own all the strings at the same time. Instead it reads them in batches (or it should) and it does not store them internally for you to reference them (or at least it should not).

Comment: It is actually tricky on the caller side too. Im using a ReadBuf that returns an Iterator<Item=String>. How would you turn this iterator into an Iterator<Item=&String>?

Comment: In that case you need to first collect the iterator into vector and then use `.iter()` on it

Comment: That's the solution I found but it seems very costly having to allocate an entire Vec just to get the references of items I already own in the iterator. Why does that make sense/ is the only way to do this?

Comment: You mean `std::io::BufRead` right?

Comment: yes, sorry, that's what I mean

Comment: @DaniloSouzaMorães is my edit of any help?